# creating double entries based on third binary variable in R

Tags: r, double

I would like to create a double entered data frame(ds2). Please see below for a visual illustration.

The variables x and y need to be recoded into two new variables respectively (x1,x2; y1,y2) based on the variable "order". Specifically, if order==1, x becomes x1; if order==2 x becomes x2. The same applies to y. Also, a new binary variable "random" need to be added selecting (1,0) one "pairId" at random.

I have made attempts using the merge function but being a total rookie I haven't found a good solution yet. Any help is highly appreciated.

```
What I have got:

> head(ds1)
     id pairId order  x   y 

     1  6826   1      74  100
     2  6826   2      70  5
     3  6371   1      70  5
     4  6371   2      71  8



What I would like to get:

> head(ds2)
     id random pairId order x1 x2  y1  y2

     1  1      6826   1     74 70  100 5
     2  0      6826   2     70 74  5   100
     3  0      6371   1     70 71  5   8
     4  1      6371   2     71 70  8   5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach I took was to only widen the data once and then rearrange (rename, really) the columns and change the value of `order`. Only after that was the randomization thrown in. Then just merged back in other dropped data (`id`) and rearranging rows and columns (these last two are not necessary, but get it to the exact format you showed).

```
library("reshape2")
library("plyr")
wide <- dcast(melt(ds1, 
                   id.vars=c("pairId", "order"), 
                   measure.vars=c("x","y")),
              pairId~variable+order)

o1 <- rename(wide, c("x_1" = "x1", "x_2" = "x2", "y_1" = "y1", "y_2" = "y2"))
o1$order = 1
o2 <- rename(wide, c("x_1" = "x2", "x_2" = "x1", "y_1" = "y2", "y_2" = "y1"))
o2$order = 2

ds2 <- rbind(o1, o2)
ds2 <- ddply(ds2, .(pairId), mutate, random = sample(c(0,1)))

# if you really need `id` in there, you can merge it back in

ds2 <- merge(ds2, ds1[c("pairId", "order", "id")])

# sorted and ordered

ds2 <- ds2[order(ds2$id),
           c("id", "random", "pairId", "order", "x1", "x2", "y1", "y2")]
```

This gives

```
> ds2
  id random pairId order x1 x2  y1  y2
3  1      0   6826     1 74 70 100   5
4  2      1   6826     2 70 74   5 100
1  3      0   6371     1 70 71   5   8
2  4      1   6371     2 71 70   8   5
```

Comment: Worked smoothly when I adapted it to my data. Thank you very much!!